# Confusing Maxima and Minima

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My question is simple what is the maximum value of (x+y) when xy=16 ?
If I individually take x=16 and y=1 then my answer is 17, but if I check z=x+16/x by derivative test taking the value from xy=16, then my minimum value is 8 but maximum value is -8, so I am confused, am I doing any kind of mistake? Any kind of help acceptable!!!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes, you are making some kind of mistake, as you get (obviously) wrong results - but without seeing your work, we can't say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Are there assumptions for valid $x,y$ values?

Comment: $17$ is not a maximum. For $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=32$ you get $x+y=32.5 >17$

Answer (score 0):

The values from differentiation are local extrema

[image]

This is the graph of $x+{16\over x}$

8 is the minimum value for positive $x$ the maximum value is infinity for positive $x$ and -8 for negative $x$

Comment: Let us remain in the domain where $x>0,y>0$. The important fact is not that the ordinate of this extrema is $8$ but that its abscissa, (which is the looked-for value) is $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x,y >0$.

Maximum:

1)Consider a rectangle with sides $x$ and $y$, and area $xy=16$.

2)$x+y$ is half the perimeter of the rectangle.

3)Vary $x$ and $y$ keeping the area$=16$.

4)Choose $x= n$;

Then $x+y=n +16/n$;

5)Consider $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Is there a maximum for $x+y$?

Minimum:

$x+y =x+16/x \ge 2\sqrt{x\cdot 16/ x} =8$

(AM-GM inequality)

Equality for $x=y=4$.

To sum it up:

The rectangle has an area$
=16$, but its perimeter $2(x+y)$ is not bounded above.